# Labels overlapping in map - Dymo-label.py

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, d3.js, topojson

I'm starting to get my hands dirty with topojson and mapping, as I'd like them to be part of my master's degree project on global warming.
I tried to do a map of Antarctica with the research stations I found online, and managed to get them right with everything.
Here's the jsfiddle for everyone who might want to take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/GtYLU/

The problem is that most of them are very close, so the labels overlap.
Following the tutorial Let's Make a Map by Mike Bostock I came acroos Dymo-label.py, a script that should do what I need.
The problem is that even with the guide I am not able to make it work. I installed everything properly (or at least seems so since it gives me no errors based on missing files etc) but when I run the script in Terminal it gives me an error about zoom, which should be expressed in the command, as shown below:

```
tom:~ tom$ cd /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Dymo
tom:Dymo tom$ python dymo-label.py --zoom=18 --minutes 2 --labels-file labels.json --places-file pointszoom5.json /Users/tom/Desktop/provaprova-z5.csv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dymo-label.py", line 242, in <module>
    for place in options.load_inputs(input_files, geometry, options.name_field, options.placement_field):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Dymo/Dymo/__init__.py", line 201, in load_places
    for (name, fontfile, fontsize, location, point, radius, properties, row, preferred) in rows:
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Dymo/Dymo/__init__.py", line 186, in load_inputs
    location, point = geometry.location_point(*row_location(row))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Dymo/Dymo/__init__.py", line 47, in location_point
    raise Exception((lat, lon, zoom))
NameError: global name 'zoom' is not defined
```

If needed I can provide the csv file, but it's the same as it's used in the map, without some fields that made conflict with dymo, the first two lines are like this (the coordinates were converted from the original file with qgis):

```
zoom,name,latitude,longitude
5,Aboa,-73,-13
```

I even put a column named zoom to try and see if it could work, but it did not. Any help would be really appreciated, since this could be very helpful for my project! Thanks in advance, Tom

Comment: and before anyone points that out: yes- I know the labels are too much  but I'd like to get dymo working for easier tasks, that one is just the first example with that problem that I came across!

Comment: You could also use a force layout to place the labels, example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/MoritzStefaner/1377729).

Comment: yeah, I saw that link when making the tutorial, but wanted to know how to make the script work, just to have another tool to use if needed! :)
thanks anyway for the reply!

Comment: There is a D3 map implementation, see: [D3js: automatic labels placement to avoid overlaps? (force repulsion)](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17434685/) / http://bl.ocks.org/pnavarrc/5913636

Note: Dymo is more powerful than the interesting previous repulsion trial. Dymo supress overlaping conflicts which can't be solve. From memory, I also suspect that the D3 repulsion approach set one repulsion node under each **label**, it thus doesn't take into account the number of letters. A solid D3 approach is yet to do.